# Argumento inválido no mmap

Tags: c, linux

Quero escrever no ficheiro "server.log" e, quando compilo o código, o resultado é "Invalid argument" na função "mmap".

```
 void MMP(){
    char* addr;
    int fd;
    struct stat sb;

    fd = open("server.log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0700);

    //para obter o tamanho do ficheiro
    if(fd == -1){
        perror("Erro na abertura do ficheiro server.log");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fstat(fd, &sb) == -1){
        perror("Erro no stat");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr = mmap((caddr_t)0, sb.st_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if(addr == -1){
       perror("Erro no mapeamento do ficheiro em memória partilhada");
       exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: coloque o parâmetro **MAP_ANONYMOUS** junto de **MAP_PRIVATE**, ficará assim
**MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE**

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro temos que deixar claro algumas coisas:

- Use *void** para a variável *addr*
- Abra o arquivo com Leitura e Escrita habilitados (*O_RDWR*). Isto é necessário para que o *mmap()* efetue o mapeamento.
- Nas permissões (o *mode* de *open()*), para criar o arquivo use *S_IRWXU* ao invés de *0700*.
- Se o tamanho de *server.log* for zero, para escrever no arquivo você precisa aumentá-lo (e o *mmap()* não aceita *length* igual a zero). **(veja próximo item)**
- Há um problema em você usar o argumento `MAP_PRIVATE` em *mmap()*:  Com `MAP_PRIVATE`, como diz no manual `user@host:~$ man 2 mmap`, o que você escrever na região mapeada não será escrito no arquivo *server.log*; e também só seu processo tem acesso à região mapeada (não é compartilhado). Para escrever em *server.log*, tanto quanto para ter o mapeamento compartilhado, você precisa usar `MAP_SHARED`, cuja implementação é um pouco diferente e vou mostrá-la mais abaixo.
- Se o *offset* for diferente de zero, ele **precisa** ser um múltiplo do valor retornado quando você chama a função *sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)*.
- Compare *addr* com *MAP_FAILED* ao invés de *-1*.
- Lembre-se no final de fechar o arquivo *close(fd)* e também de "desmapeá-lo" com *munmap(addr, tamanho da região mapeada)*.
- E lembre-se também de incluir todos os headers (cabeçalhos) necessários no início do código.

Por via das dúvidas:
<sup>protótipo de *open()*</sup>
  `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);`
<sup>protótipo do *mmap()*</sup>
  `void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,`
  `int fd, off_t offset);`

### O Código

---

Primeiro tentei fazer uma versão do seu código (com *MAP_PRIVATE*) corrigida (comentei ela com alguns dos itens que falei acima):
Compile-a com: `gcc mmap.c -o mmap`

mmap.c

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (void) {
    int fd;
    void *addr; /* use void*  */
    struct stat sb;

    int retval = 0; /* valor que será retornado por main() */

    /* use O_RDWR ao invés de O_WRONLY ( necessário para o mmap() )
     * e também S_IRWXU ao invés de 00700 */
    if ((fd = open("server.log", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    /* fstat() para obter o tamanho do arquivo */
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        retval = 1;
        goto _go_close_fd;
    }

    /* se o tamanho for igual a zero, precisamos aumentá-lo!
     * Caso contrário não conseguiremos escrever nada e mmap() vai falhar */
    if (sb.st_size == 0) {
        printf("file size is zero!\n");
        ftruncate(fd, 1024); /* __define__ o tamanho do arquivo
                              * (não aumenta em cima do que já é) */
        sb.st_size = 1024;
    }

    /* use NULL no primeiro argumento */
    /* E se quiser usar outro offset, este precisa ser maior que o valor
     * retornado por  sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)  */
    addr = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) { /* use MAP_FAILED ao invés de -1 */
        perror("mmap"); /* "memória partilhada"?  MAP_PRIVATE inibe o
                         * compartilhamento do map(eamento) e também não
                         * escreve suas alterações no arquivo em disco.
                         * Se quiser compartilhar com outros processos e
                         * também "salvar" o que escreveu no arquivo
                         * deve usar MAP_SHARED */
        goto _go_close_fd;
    }

    /* **************************************************************
     * Escreva o que quiser no arquivo mapeado DESDE QUE não exceda o
     * tamanho do arquivo `sb.st_size`. E lembre-se de que nada será
     * "salvo" (transferido) para o arquivo `server.log` no disco
     * ************************************************************** */

    munmap(addr, sb.st_size); /* unmap o file descriptor */
_go_close_fd:
    close(fd); /* precisamos fechar o file descriptor */
    return retval;
}
```

Este outro código usa *MAP_SHARED* e escreve no arquivo (tirei alguns comentários para deixar o código o mais limpo possível):
Compile-o com: `gcc mmap_shared.c -o mmap_shared`

mmap_shared.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (void) {
    int fd;
    void *addr;
    struct stat sb;

    int retval = 0; /* valor que será retornado por main() */

    if ((fd = open("server.log", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        retval = 1;
        goto _go_close_fd;
    }

    if (sb.st_size == 0) {
        printf("file size is zero!\n");
        ftruncate(fd, 1024);
        sb.st_size = 1024;
    }

    /* se quiser pode mapear além do tamanho do arquivo, mas o que escrever
     * nesta memória além-arquivo não irá ter efeito nele :-) */
    addr = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        goto _go_close_fd;
    }

    /* **************************************************************
     * Escreva o que quiser no arquivo mapeado DESDE QUE não exceda o
     * tamanho do arquivo `sb.st_size`. Exemplo:
     * ************************************************************** */
    snprintf((char*) addr, sb.st_size, "Hello World!\n");

    /* vamos usar msync() para ter certeza que nossa informação irá para o
     * arquivo em disco!
     * msync() faz um flush nos dados :-)
     * -> A flag MS_SYNC diz que msync só irá retornar para a gente quando
     *    a informação for escrita no arquivo */
    msync(addr, sb.st_size, MS_SYNC);

    munmap(addr, sb.st_size); /* unmap o file descriptor */
_go_close_fd:
    close(fd); /* precisamos fechar o file descriptor */
    return retval;
}
```

O que mudei do 1º para este 2º código foi a flag *MAP_SHARED*, o *snprintf()* que adicionei e o *msync()* que garante a escrita no arquivo.
Para mais detalhes veja estes manuais (em Inglês):
[ftruncate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html), [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [msync](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html), [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) e [snprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html)